# Efficient view controller management in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

In an era of the seamless swipe navigation style apps, such as Snapchat, view controller management seems to be of importance. Some views could be fat, some could have large amounts of data populated to them. When building an iOS app that has 5-10 views sitting on a 2-dimensional surface (*swipe left for view X, swipe down for view Y, swipe down again for view Z and so on*), what are some best practices in handling these view controllers? I make the assumption that one wants to be able to do some kind of keyframe animations to UI elements in these views.

The plausible solutions that I can see are:

1. **Add all of the view controllers to a 2d scroll view and selectively lock scroll direction**

   - Pros: Easy to setup, easy to to keyframe animations to subviews (using [Jazzhands](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands), for example)
   - Cons: Need to keep many view controllers alive, potentially heavy on
     resources and long startup time.
2. **Add view controllers to a 2d scroll view and selectively lock scroll direction, but only populate them when needed**

   - Pros: Could bring down startup time, also easy to to keyframe animations
   - Cons: We still need to keep all view controllers alive
3. **Use gesture driven view controller presentation animations**

   - Pros: We only need to keep the current view controller and its root view controllers alive
   - Cons: More cumbersome to setup. Harder to perform keyframe animations based on scrolling. Could add lag when presenting big view controllers

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to use a `UINavigationController` and push and pop your view controllers from the navigation stack as needed.

You can control the animation between the view controllers by implementing the [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning) protocol. This way you can transition using any type of animation you can imagine.

Comment: This is what I meant by option 3. But what if you have one really heavy view, like a camera view (like snapchat). This would add delays when scrolling back and forth, wouldnt it?

Comment: There is a difference between presenting a view controller and pushing and popping to a navigation stack. Delays would not be an issue as long as you are loading your view controllers appropriately for your needs.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 are definitely bad practice with terrible resource management